# unable to click on a list element with in <nav> and <ul> tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, xvfb

I have a list of elements within nav tag. I want to click on first list element. My HTML is given below:

```
<aside id="left-panel" style="overflow: visible;">
   <div id="selectedBrand" class="custum-brand-info login-info">
      <span class="dropdown">
    </div>
    <nav>
       <ul id="sideNavigation">
          <li>
             <a onclick="showHideBrandmanagement(true);" href="/sentiment/view">
                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                <span class="menu-item-parent">Sentiment</span>
             </a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

My test case has failed sometimes; my test case passed but sometimes it failed.
I am running my test case in **headless** mode using **XVFB**.

should get the data  within topic *** FAILED ***

```
[info]   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#left-panel nav #sideNavigation li:nth-child(9) #rAnalytics"}
[info] Command duration or timeout: 10.06 seconds
[info] For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
[info] Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
[info] System info: host: 'knoldus-Vostro-2520', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
[info] *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#left-panel nav #sideNavigation li:nth-child(9) #rAnalytics}
[info] Session ID: edc0a525-38bb-48b2-88c4-e1ad01265c15
[info] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
[info] Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=41.0}]
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[info]   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
[info]   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
[info]   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
[info]   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
[info]   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
[info]   at selenium.professionalPlan.Topic$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Topic.scala:31)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#left-panel nav #sideNavigation li:nth-child(9) #rAnalytics"}
[info] For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
[info] Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
[info] System info: host: 'knoldus-Vostro-2520', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
[info] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[info]   at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///tmp/anonymous5218088375039490898webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10667)
[info]   at .fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///tmp/anonymous5218088375039490898webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:623)
[1]
```

I have tried Xpath, cssSelector, even I manually provide an id to first anchor tag, but my test case failed and I got an exception.

Comment: Please notice, I can't add a comment and this is not a solution.
I found it some time with Headless the element can't not be found. Can you start with FirefoxDriver first and see if it works.

Comment: Test the xpath supplied  from Shubham with Headless it works fine.

Comment: thanx alan but the xpath supplied by shubham is not working i have tried it bt i have got the same error again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate just an id then use

```
//nav[1]/ul[@id='sideNavigation']
```

But above xpath will return you many elements.

If you looking for the element that contains `"Sentiment"` text, Then use below Xpath:-

```
//nav[1]/ul[@id='sideNavigation']//span[contains(text(),'Sentiment')]
```

If still it is not working then check whether do you have any frame in your page. If that frame contains your HTML code of above element then you need to switch to frame first

Please try with below code also:-

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[1]/ul[@id='sideNavigation']//span[contains(text(),'Sentiment')]"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript(js, elem);;
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: tahnx shubham for ur help and i have tried it but  i have got the same error again. when i manually provide a id to the <a> thag like <a id="sentiment" onclick="showHideBrandmanagement(true);" href="/sentiment/view"> and then use findElementById("sentiment") .is displayed then it shoul return true bt it returning false and the error is same as prior ....

Comment: i have checked it that there is any frame or not but there is no frame available its simple html code

Comment: If you search by ID ideally you should get only one/zero element. In valid HTML ID should be unique.

Comment: I have updated my answer. can you please try that one also

Comment: thanx but it throws an exception like value driver is not a member of object org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor i have imported the file org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;